# Sampling weights to generate mapping between two similar pdfs

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Assume two r.v. $X \sim D(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim D(\mu+\beta, \sigma^2)$.  I have a sample of each r.v., lets call these samples $sX$ and $sY$.  Using these samples, I can generate empirical pdf's for each distribution, $f(x)$ and $g(y)$.

#### Desire:

I'd like to replication $g(y)$ by re-weighing the observation in $sX$ and then using these weight, make draws from $sX$ .  Said another way, I need to know how to weigh each observation in $sX$ such that when I draw from $sX$ I obtain $g(y)$.

I'm not sure if this is possible for a general distribution.  If its not possible, assume a normal distribution.

#### Attempts

Originally, I thought that for a given observation $z$ the appropriate weight might be $G(z)$/$F(z)$, where $G$ and $F$ are cdfs.  However, testing with a normal distribution, it didn't not appear to work. $G(z)^2$/$F(z)$ was a better weight.

Comment: This is both possible and *easy* for a distribution in an Exponential family, essentially by virtue of its definition.  It is crucial, though, that the elements of $sX$ cover most of the probable values that can be drawn from $D(\mu+\beta,\sigma^2)$. Otherwise you will get, in effect, a *truncated* version of that distribution.